# Pascal Illegal Expression

Tags: loops, if-statement, pascal

It stops compiling at lines 54 and 58 with errors 'Error: Illegal expression' and 'Syntax error, ; expected but ELSE found' respectively. Is my position of the lines wrong?

```
Procedure PlayDiceGame(PlayerOneName, PlayerTwoName : String;
                           VirtualDiceGame : Boolean; Var TopScores : TTopScores);
      Var
        PlayerOut : Boolean;
        CurrentPlayerScore : Integer;
        AppealDieResult : Integer;
        PlayerNo : Integer;
        PlayerOneScore : Integer;
        PlayerTwoScore : Integer;
        BowlDieResult : Integer;
        RunsScored : Integer;
        NumberOfBalls : Integer;
      Begin
        For PlayerNo := 1 To 2
          Do
            Begin
            NumberOfBalls := 0;
              CurrentPlayerScore := 0;
              PlayerOut := False;
              If PlayerNo = 1
                Then Writeln(PlayerOneName, ' is batting')
                Else Writeln(PlayerTwoName, ' is batting');
              Writeln;
              Writeln('Press the Enter key to continue');
              Readln;
              Repeat
                BowlDieResult := RollBowlDie(VirtualDiceGame);
                If BowlDieResult In [1..4]
                  Then
                    Begin
                      RunsScored := CalculateRunsScored(BowlDieResult);
                      DisplayRunsScored(RunsScored);
                      CurrentPlayerScore := CurrentPlayerScore + RunsScored;
                      Writeln('Your new score is: ', CurrentPlayerScore);
                    End;
                If BowlDieResult = 5
                  Then Writeln('No runs scored this time.  Your score is still: ',
                              CurrentPlayerScore);
                If BowlDieResult = 6
                  Then
                    Begin
                      Writeln('This could be out... press the Enter key to find out.');
                      Readln;
                      AppealDieResult := RollAppealDie(VirtualDiceGame);
                      DisplayAppealDieResult(AppealDieResult);
                      If AppealDieResult >= 2
                        Then PlayerOut := True
                        Else PlayerOut := False;
                    End;
                Writeln;
                Writeln('Press the Enter key to continue');
                Readln;
                NumberOfBalls = NumberOfBalls + 1
              Until PlayerOut or (NumberOfBalls = 6);
              If (NumberOfBalls = 6) Then
              Writeln('You have faced 6 balls and compeletd your innings');
              Writeln('Your final scoare was: ', CurrentPlayerScore);
              Else
              Writeln('You are out.  Your final score was: ', CurrentPlayerScore);
              Writeln;
              Writeln('Press the Enter key to continue');
              Readln;
              If PlayerNo = 1
                Then PlayerOneScore := CurrentPlayerScore
                Else PlayerTwoScore := CurrentPlayerScore;
            End;
        DisplayResult(PlayerOneName, PlayerOneScore, PlayerTwoName, PlayerTwoScore);
        If (PlayerOneScore >= PlayerTwoScore)
          Then
            Begin
              UpdateTopScores(TopScores, PlayerOneName, PlayerOneScore);
              UpdateTopScores(TopScores, PlayerTwoName, PlayerTwoScore);
            End
          Else
            Begin
              UpdateTopScores(TopScores, PlayerTwoName, PlayerTwoScore);
              UpdateTopScores(TopScores, PlayerOneName, PlayerOneScore);
            End;
        Writeln;
        Writeln('Press the Enter key to continue');
        Readln;
      End;
```

Comment: Normally you write `for i := 0 to 5 do` (example), that is, the `do` is on the same line as the `for`. Similarily, one usually writes `if 1+1=2 then` with the `then` on the same line as the `if`.

Comment: We don't know for sure without the rest of the file. But the answers below indicate that there are indeed 2 errors in the code shown here.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand: Code formatting is not the problem here, and there are different rules used in some places. Jeffs code is (mostly) syntactically correct.

Comment: @Turbo J: Yes, of course it is. Code formatting in Delphi is always a matter of taste. But since it is very uncommon to place the `do` and `then` on its own line, and since it makes it harder to get 'subtle' details like when you need to create a block of code by using `begin` and `end`, I made a comment about it. Of course I don't think that the problems are coused by the unusual use of whitespace, and, what's more, had I believed so, I would have written an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: JFI: Here are "official" Pascal (as in Delphi) formatting guidelines: http://www.econos.de/delphi/cs.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a multi-line `then` block

```
If (NumberOfBalls = 6) Then
    Writeln('You have faced 6 balls and compeletd your innings');
    Writeln('Your final scoare was: ', CurrentPlayerScore);
Else
```

Wrap it in begin/end and it should work.

Comment: Wrapped it but I get the ; expected but ELSE found error still.

Comment: @Jeff Howard has quoted the *old* (your) code instead of correct one. THe correct one is `if ... then begin statement1; statement2; end else begin statement3; statement4; end;`

Comment: @Eugene Thanks. Also thanks to @Andreas about explaining the End statements with semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
NumberOfBalls = NumberOfBalls + 1
```

to

```
NumberOfBalls := NumberOfBalls + 1
```

and put the writeln statements in a begin-end block.

Comment: Nitpick: Add the missing semicolon to correctly end the statement.

Comment: @Turbo J: In Delphi you do not need to end statements with semicolon. You only need to use semicolon to separate two statements from eachother. That is, `begin a := 5 end` is valid, but you need the semicolon in `begin a := 5; b := 10 end`

Answer (score 0):

You dont write ; before the else in the if sentence. It ends the whole sentence, skipping the else, and it will surely give you an error.